# function appendItemの使い方について

Tags: javascript, d3.js

現在こちら( http://qiita.com/tag1216/items/b7f846af66db30b8c393 )( http://qiita.com/tag1216/items/ad406625dc654d3c0982 )を参考にプログラムを作成しています。
１つ目のurlを参考にはてなブックマーク版のプログラムを作成しました。
以下がそのソースになります。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<style>
 svg {
    border: solid 1px;
}
.node circle {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: .5px;
    opacity: .7;
}
.node text {
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}
.node .shadow {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-opacity: .7;
}
.node .text {
}
.link {
    stroke: #888;
    opacity: .3;
}
 </style>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3.js(Force Layout)の練習</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>



  <script>
  function pointer(){
     var object = document.getElementById('object');
   if (object.contentDocument)
   var svgdoc = object.getSVGDocument();
   var svgelm = svgdoc.documentElement.style.cursor='pointer';
 }


  var w = 1024;
  var h = 800;

  var nodes = [];
  var links = [];
  var xlink = [];
  var link2 = [];
  var tags = [];
  var items = [];
  var Tag = [];
  var nodes2 = [];
  var links2 = [];





  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var NAME_PREFIX = "_";


  /* var url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry&num=-1";
  var proxy_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/" + encodeURIComponent(url); */


  function for_each(array, func){ Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, func); }

  function get_html(callback){
   var hatena_hotentry_url = "http://b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry";
   hatena_hotentry_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/"
    + encodeURIComponent(hatena_hotentry_url);






   /* var hatena_hotentry_url = "./hatena_hotentry.html" */

   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", hatena_hotentry_url);
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
     callback(req.responseText);
     req = undefined;
    }
   };
   req.send(null);
  }

  function html_to_relation(html){
   var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
   var error_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
   if(error_tags.length){
    console.log("error: ", error_tags);
    return [["Parse error", "Maybe HTML is broken"]];
   }

   var relation = []; /*// [["name", ...], ...]
  */ var entry_elms = doc.querySelectorAll(
     "[data-track-section='default'] .entry-contents");
   for_each(entry_elms, function(entry_elm){
    var entry_link_elm = entry_elm.querySelector(".entry-link");
    if(!entry_link_elm){ return; }

    var name_array = [];
    relation.push(name_array);
     name_array.push(entry_link_elm.href);
    name_array.push(entry_link_elm.title);



    var entry_meta_elm = entry_elm.nextElementSibling;
    if(!entry_meta_elm){ return; }
    for_each(entry_meta_elm.querySelectorAll("a.tag"), function(tag_elm){

      name_array.push(tag_elm.textContent);
    });


   });

   return relation;
   }






  function relation_view(relation){
   /*document.getElementById("view").textContent
           = JSON.stringify(relation, undefined, 2);
  */



  /* d3.json(proxy_url,function(error,json){
  if(error){
   return console.warn(error);
  }

  var feeds = json.responseData.feed;

  for(var x = 0;x < feeds.entries.length;x++){
   var href = {"url": feeds.entries[x].link};
   xlink.push(href);
  };

  }); */


 var d = [];
 var normal = [];

   for(var i = 0;i<relation.length;i++){
      if(i+1 < relation.length){
          var num ={"source":  i ,"target": + (i+1) };
      }else{
          var num ={"source":  i , "target": 0};
      }
     /*  var list = {"label": relation[i][1]  , "url": relation[i][0],
            "tag":relation[i][2] +","+ relation[i][3] +","+ relation[i][4] +","+ relation[i][5]}; */




            var sub1 = relation[i][2];
             var sub2 = relation[i][3];
             var sub3 = relation[i][4];
             var sub4 = relation[i][5];



             var a1 = {"name":sub1,"url":'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + sub1};
             var a2 = {"name":sub2,"url":'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + sub2};
              var a3 = {"name":sub3,"url":'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + sub3};
             var a4 = {"name":sub4,"url":'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + sub4};
             var c = [];
             c.push(a2,a3,a4);
             normal.push(a2,a3,a4);
             /*  a.push(sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4); */


      var list = {"label": relation[i][1]  , "url": relation[i][0],
      "tags":c};

       /* var subtags = {"tag":relation[i][2] + relation[i][3] + relation[i][4] + relation[i][5]}; */

    /*  var sub1 = relation[i][2];
     var sub2 = relation[i][3];
     var sub3 = relation[i][4];
     var sub4 = relation[i][5];

     var a = [];
     var supersub = {"tag":a};
     a.push(sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4);




     console.log(supersub); */





    /* a.name  = [sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4]; */







        nodes.push(list);
             links.push(num);



   }


  console.log(nodes)



 var tags = nodes.reduce(function(tags,item){
    items.push(item);
    console.log(items)
     item.tags.forEach(function(tag){
   var name = NAME_PREFIX + tag.name;
    if(!(name in tags)){
     tags[name] = {
       name:tag.name,
       urlName:tag.url,
       count:0
     };
    }
    tags[name].count++;
   });
   return tags;
 },[]);




   var nodes2 = d3.values(tags)
      .sort(function(tag1,tag2){
      return tag1.count - tag2.count;
     });
  console.log(nodes2)





  var tagLinks = nodes.reduce(function(links,item){
     item.tags.forEach(function(tag1){

      item.tags.forEach(function(tag2){
       var key = tag1.name + NAME_PREFIX + tag2.name;
       if(!(key in links)){
        links[key] = {
          source:nodes2.indexOf(tags[NAME_PREFIX + tag1.name]),
          target:nodes2.indexOf(tags[NAME_PREFIX + tag2.name]),
          count:0
        };
       }
       links[key].count++;
      })
     })
     return links;
  },[]);

     console.log(tagLinks)




     var links2 = d3.values(tagLinks);
     console.log(links2)
    /*  var tags =  relation.reduce(function(tags,item){
    relation.forEach(function(tag){
     var name = NAME_PREFIX + tag;
     if(!(name in tags)){
      tags[name] = {
          name:tag,
          urlname:'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + tag,
          count:0
      };
     }
     tags[name].count++;
    });
    return tags;
  },[]);


    var nodes = d3.values(tags)
      .sort(function(tag1,tag2){
      return tag1.count - tag2.count;
   });
 */




   /* var tagLinks = relation.reduce(function(links,item){
   relation.forEach(function(tag1){
    relation.forEach(function(tag2){
     var key = tag1.name + NAME_PREFIX + tag2.name;
    if(!(key in links)){
     links[key] = {
         source:nodes.indexOf(tags[NAME_PREFIX + tag1.name]),
         target:nodes.indexOf(tags[NAME_PREFIX + tag2.name]),
         count:0
     };
    }
    links[key].count++;
    })
   })
   return links;
  },[]); */


    /* var links = d3.values(tagLinks); */










     var force = d3.layout.force()
          .size([w, h])
          .linkStrength(1.0)
          .friction(0.1)
          .linkDistance(400)
          .charge(function(d){return -200;})
          .gravity(0.2);


    /*console.log(nodes)*/

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width:w, height:h});

     /* var link = svg.selectAll("line")
          .data(links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .style({stroke: "#ccc",
                  "stroke-width": 1}); */



         force
           .nodes(nodes2)
           .links(links2)
           .start();


         /* var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
           .data(links2)
           .enter()
           .append('line')
           .attr('class','link')
           .style({stroke: "#ccc",
                          "stroke-width": 1}); */

            var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
                      .data(links2)
                     .enter().append('line')
                      .attr('class', 'link')
                       .style('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.count * d.count; });



         var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(nodes2)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','node')
            .call(force.drag);

         var a = node.append('a')
            .attr('xlink:href',function(d){return 'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/tag?q=' + d.name;})
            .attr('target','_blank');


         a.append('circle')
         .attr('r', function(d) { return 9 * Math.sqrt(d.count) })
         .style('fill', function(d) { return color(d.index); })
         .on('mouseover', function(d) { d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).style('z-index', 999); })
         .on('mouseout', function(d) { d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).style('z-index', null); })

     node.append('text')
         .attr('class', 'shadow')
         .attr('dx', 0)
         .attr('dy', '.5em')
         .style('font-size', function(d) { return (2*Math.sqrt(d.count)) + 'px' })
         .text(function(d) { return d.name + '(' + d.count + ')'; })



     node.append('title')
         .text(function(d) { return d.name + ':' + d.count; });




         /* /* var node = svg.selectAll("a")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("a")
     .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return d.url;})
     .attr('target','_blank')
     .append("circle")
     .attr({r:20,opacity:0.5})

     .style('fill',function(d){ return color(d.index);})
     .on('mouseover',function(d){d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).style('z-index',999);})
     .on('mouseout',function(d){d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).style('z-index',null);})
     .attr('class','node') */



    /*  .call(force.drag);
 */

     /* var label = svg.selectAll('text')
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append('text')
     .attr('class','shadow')
     .attr('dx',0)
     .attr('dy','.5em')
     .style({"font-size":5})
     .attr({"text-anchor":"middle",
         "fill":"black"})

     .text(function(d){return d.label;})


    node.append('title')
    .text(function(d){return d.label;}); */



     /* var label = svg.selectAll('text')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class','shadow')
      .attr('dx',0)
      .attr('dy','5em')
      .attr({"text-anchor":"middle",
         "fill":"black"})
      .attr({'pointer-events' : 'none'})
      .style('font-size',function(d){ return (6* Math.sqrt(d.count)) + 'px'})
      .text(function(d){return d.label;}); */




      force.on("tick", function() {
     link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
         /*  link.attr({x1: function(d) { return d.source.x; },
                     y1: function(d) { return d.source.y; },
                     x2: function(d) { return d.target.x; },
                     y2: function(d) { return d.target.y; }}); */
           node.attr('transform',function(d){return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; });
          /* node.attr({cx: function(d) { return d.x; }
                     cy: function(d) { return d.y; }}); */
           /* label.attr({x: function(d) { return d.x;},
               y: function(d) { return d.y }}); */

  })
  }



  get_html(function(html){ relation_view(html_to_relation(html)); });






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

１つ目の参考urlから２つ目のurlのプログラムのように書き換えを行いたいのですが、２つ目のurlの

```
function appendItem(item) {
items.push(item);
nodes.push(item);
item.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    var name = "___" + tag.name;
    if (!(name in tags)) {
        tags[name] = tag;
        tags[name].count = 0;
        nodes.push(tags[name]);
    }
    tags[name].count++;
    links.push({
        source: nodes.indexOf(item),
        target: nodes.indexOf(tags[name])
    });
});
restart();
```

}
この部分の書き換えが上手くいきません。
appendItemの要素にnodes配列を読み込ませたいのですが、どのようにすれば読み込ませることができるでしょうか？

恐縮ではございますが、お力添え宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: コメントアウトされているコードやnormal変数あたりは、試行錯誤の名残でしょうか？また、括弧の対応に誤りがあるのか、構文エラーも出ています。回答しようとあなたのコードを読んで試すときにそこで躓かないように、[質問したいこと以外の問題は取り除いてから](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)コードを貼り付けていただけると助かります。

Comment: appendItemの中で追加するはずのnodesやlinksにappendItemの外で追加しているようですが、何故そうしようと思ったのですか？appendItemに渡すべきitemが知りたいのではないのでしょうか。

Comment: unarist様
ご回答ありがとうございます。ソースに関してはすぐに直したいと思います。
nodesやlinksを外でなぜ追加しているのかという件についてですが、参考にさせて頂いているソースはqiitaのAPIにおいてもともと配列に情報が格納されたまま返ってきますが、はてなブックマークに同じ仕様のAPIがありません。
それを実現するためにはてなブックマークの新着エントリ―のページをスクレイピングしそれを配列に当てはめております。その配列にアクセスするためのfunction内で書こうとした結果こうなっております。
変数nodesにはqiitaのＡＰＩで返ってくる情報に似せたものを格納しています。それをd3,jsに使うノードの情報をnodes2に格納して利用しています。

Comment: 1つめと2つめではプログラムの構造がだいぶ変わっているので、書き換えるよりも2つめに組み込みなおしたほうが早いかもしれませんが・・・私は当初「`appendItem()` の引数に何を渡せばいいのか」についてお答えしようかと思っていたのですが、そういう質問ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ございません。appenItem()の引数にはnodesを渡すことができればプログラムは動くはずだと自分で考えておりました。正確には引数にnodesの渡し方がわからずそれをお尋ねしようと思っておりました。文章能力が低く、伝える力が不足しておりました。大変申し訳ございません...。

Answer (score 1):

d3.jsのForce Layoutで使用するデータは次のような形式です（以下の例では`node1`と`node2`、また、`node1`と`node3`の間がリンクされます）。

```
var nodes = [
  {"name": "node1"},
  {"name": "node2"},
  {"name": "node3"}
];

var links = [
  {"source": 0, "target": 1},
  {"source": 0, "target": 2}
];
```

Comment: @dadada さんの必要としているコードは [こちら](https://github.com/cosmology233/cosmology233.github.io/blob/master/works/temporary/20151212/javascripts/script.js) に近いものになるかと思います。デモは [こちら](https://cosmology233.github.io/works/temporary/20151212/) を確認してください（ノードをクリックするとログが出ます）。

Comment: まずそれぞれのメソッドの動きを調べて処理の流れを追って見るべきだと思いますよ。メソッドに関する具体的な質問であれば答えてくださる方は多いです。[良い質問をするには? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Kazma Arakaki様
ご回答ありがとうございます。ソースについても有用な意見非常に助かりました。
メソッドの動きに関してなのですが、当方出来る限りの流れを追ってみたのですがわからなかったため質問させて頂きました。
nodeとlinkの形式についてですが、書籍にも目を通し一応ひとつのプログラムを作ることには成功致しました。( http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19934/d3-js%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6 )
上記のようにプログラムの書き換えを行いたく、今回この質問をさせて頂きました。
その中で詰まったところがappendItemだったため今回この質問をさせて頂きました。
非常にわかりにくい形となってしまい、申し訳ありませんでした。